# How can I extract sound drivers from Suse for use in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, sound, extract

So I have a bit of a dilemma, I want to use Ubuntu on my home desktop. The problem is that I use a fancy sound card that Ubuntu doesn't support. I use an HT Omega Striker 7.1. The manufacturer only makes Windows drivers.

After an exhaustive amount of searching I have found two things. The first is that there is a forum post that has been repeated over and over again that is supposed to contain drivers for Ubuntu but in fact only contains one uncompiled C source file that references a ton of other files that don't come in the downloaded compressed file. So it is worthless.

The second is that supposedly Suse does support/work with my sound card. I am in the process of downloading OpenSuse to test this out. But in the mean time I would really like to know how, if it does in fact work via a Live CD test, would I go about extracting that driver from OpenSuse and using it on Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: Its highly unlikely that Suse has the sound driver and Ubuntu does not.

Comment: I am just repeating what I have seen in the forums about it. I will probably get a chance to test this tonight or tomorrow night after work.

Answer (score 1):

The "drivers" in linux are kernel modules. So if the sound card works in SUSE it should work in any distro with the same kernel version or higher.

If not you could build a custom kernel and enable it.

Of course you could always get a linux compatible sound card ;)

Comment: +1 ...... I have checked your profile many times age 91 ... are you really ?

Comment: Ok, but this isn't the first time I have heard of some device working better (or at all) in one distro but not in another. Is there an extra layer for sound card control that could be affecting this that is different in Suse than Ubuntu? Also I would get another one but I really don't want to shell out more money to replace a sound card that works well in so many other cases.

Comment: As I said, it is typically a kernel issue and not a distro issue. First step is to see if it is working in SUSE, if so, why ?